# Calling a Controller Action from a View... Or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I'll keep it short: Should I call `Controller2.getByCriteria(some, criteria, here)` from `Controller1` then set an instance variable for the view to use, or should I call it from `Controller1`'s view using something like `= render Controller2.getByCriteria(some, criteria, here)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, calling one controller's action from another is a design error. It either means you have common business  logic, which implies the code should be in `models` (or maybe `lib`) or you have common view logic, which implies the code should be in `helpers`.

So in your case, I think using a helper seems apt:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  # ...
  def getByCriteria(some, criteria, here)
    # handle criteria here
    # Something like: 
    # render :partial => 'foo'
  end
  # ...
end
```

And then simply call it from the views.

If you want a full controller/view like component sharing across your application, you can use a gem called [`cells`](http://rubygems.org/gems/cells). It enables you to create re-usable controller and view components.

Comment: Can I do something like
= render getByCriteria(some, criteria, here)
in the view and have getByCriteria() return an array?

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to do this is to declare the controller method (not controller action) as a helper.

[See here](http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method).